# how to support multiple displays Unity UWP apps

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp

I need to develop an augmented reality application using vuforia, and now that it supports UWP I think is possible to use this library for a windows pc application, but when I change my unity project for windows store on build settings I notice that multiple displays support doesn't appear to be found. My application needs to be displayed on two monitors where on one monitor is the augmented content and on the other is some kind of gui interaction.

So my question is how can I support multiple displays in UWP (not windows build stand alone)?

In the forum of unity suggest me to create a c++ plugin for this because unity by default is not supported.
Suggest me in the plugin to create a new window, and create a swapchain for it and then pass the render texture of the camera I want to display in the window, but I tried but without success.

Also what I'm thinking is if I accomplish this and pass my GUI in to this windows I could not interact with my gui because is just a texture that I'm displaying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity3D: Displaying different scenes on multiple monitors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618597/unity3d-displaying-different-scenes-on-multiple-monitors). You don't even need a plugin to use multi display in Unity

Comment: Is not duplicate because the solution of the thread is for standalone windows applications not for UWP applications.
Also the answer say some things that are not available in UWP (windows store) builds